# Which one is better for jQuery.ajax calls? .Net Web-Service or an .ashx?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, jquery, ashx

I ahve been practicing jQuery.ajax() recently. I have started to learn to call .Net web-services qith jQuery.ajax().

Now I am considering if I will use **only** jQuery.ajax() calls to some service methods on the server; is it still meaningfull to have .Net Web-Services or I should go with .ashx handlers instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Two quotes from [the ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1445088.aspx/1):

> Unless it's an extremely high load situation, you'll find that all
>   three perform nearly identically.  The performance of your code inside
>   the handler/service is going to be the limiting factor.
>
> For simple AJAX calls that are only intended to be exposed to the
>   browser, I don't think WCF justifies its added complexity. It's great
>   for some things, but I have a hard time recommending it for this.
>
> Between ASMX and HttpHandler, I go with ASMX every time.  An
>   HttpHandler is probably negligibly faster, but an ASMX "ScriptService"
>   makes JSON serialization and deserialization of complex types
>   transparent, which is immensely useful.

---

> Here's another option:
>
> If you have some methods you want to run (and you like JQuery)... I
>   suggest looking at this:
>
> http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
>
> and related articles.  Works beautiful.  Very efficient as far as
>   bandwith goes.  They also have an article on querying .asmx services.
>
> There is no messing around with the bloated size of ASP.NET's innate
>   AJAX.  Since AJAX out of the box can be very bloated.  Plus it's very
>   easy.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a look at microsoft's most recent framework for web services: [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Personally, I recently switched to [ServiceStack.NET](http://www.servicestack.net/) for my web services, and I find it's a lot easier and elegant (than WebAPI, or WCF).

Answer (score 0):

a WCF service would be the preferred method over ASP.NET soap web services or ashx services .

Comment: ASMX services shouldn't be confused with "SOAP web services". In fact, the JSON that ASMX "ScriptServices" produce is more useful in a couple ways (Dictionaries and Enums) and its JSON [de]serializer (JavaScriptSerializer) receives input parameters more flexible than WCF's (DataContractJsonSerializer) in a couple other ways (DateTimes and Enums).